# How do i get IntelliJ to pick up my environment variables on MacOS X?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, gemfile

I have tried to set these using RCenvironment, .bashrc, .MacOSX/environment.plist and /etc/launchd.conf and restarted computer....IntelliJ is still not picking up my env variables:

Gemfile
    p "ENVIRONMENT: #{ENV['VAR_PRIVATE_GEM_USERNAME']}" # Outputs "ENVIRONMENT: "

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the related questions:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51677
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57385

Your question is not specific to IntelliJ IDEA at all.

On **Mountain Lion** solutions from the first link will not work, so you can do something like this in the Terminal:

```
export VAR_PRIVATE_GEM_USERNAME=John
open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 11.app/
```

Also note that many Run/Debug configurations in IntelliJ IDEA allow to set custom environment variables:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can set an environment variable on a Mac that will be available in all apps (not just the command line) by using "launchctl" (see https://ss64.com/osx/launchctl.html)

```
launchctl setenv VARIABLE_NAME VALUE
```

Comment: That would require you to turn off the System Integrity Protection which is also not ok